# LOAD DATA INFILE tough query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query, that works:

```
    mysql -u root --local-infile=1 home -e "
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$1'
    INTO TABLE $TABLE_NAME
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
      (size, @d2, @d3, @d4, @d5, path, @d6)
    SET last_modified=str_to_date(
      CONCAT(@d2, ',', @d3, ',', @d4, ',', @d5), '%b,%d,%T,%Y')
```

I also need to set a column called `volume` = 1. This is what I tried:

```
    mysql -u root --local-infile=1 home -e "
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$1'
    INTO TABLE $TABLE_NAME
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
      (size, @d2, @d3, @d4, @d5, path, @d6)
    SET last_modified=str_to_date(
      CONCAT(@d2, ',', @d3, ',', @d4, ',', @d5), '%b,%d,%T,%Y') 
    and SET volume=1;"
```

Though I get an sql error. What would be the corerct way to update `volume=1` above?

Comment: To set multiple columns, separate them with `,`, not `and`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax should be:

```
 mysql -u root --local-infile=1 home -e "
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$1'
    INTO TABLE $TABLE_NAME
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
      (size, @d2, @d3, @d4, @d5, path, @d6)
    SET last_modified=str_to_date(
      CONCAT(@d2, ',', @d3, ',', @d4, ',', @d5), '%b,%d,%T,%Y') 
    ,volume=1;"
```

It should be using standard `UPDATE` statement syntax where your SET options are comma separated

```
...
SET last_modified=blah, volume=1
```

As Barmar stated, here is the link to MySQL's documentation regarding `LOAD DATA`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: Why assume, it confirms it in the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: Because I figured it's a safe assumption.  Why would they change the syntax of the SET keyword?  Maybe I shouldn't have said it was an assumption, but it was :P

Comment: Ok fine, got rid of my "assumption" :P